# Is this nonlinear system "solvable"?

Tags: nonlinear-system, characteristics

I don't really mean solvable, what I mean is: is it possible to rewrite $w$ in terms of $y$ and $z$?
$$w =e^{3s}(1+r) -1$$
$$y = se^{2s}$$ 
$$z = 2se^{2s}(1+r) +r$$

I have fooled around with this for about an hour and the best thing I've got is that I can rewrite $r$ as a function of $y$ and $z$ only but I can't find one for $s$. Is there a "go to" method for these nonlinear systems or is it just a solve it any way you can type thing? Is there a way to know if it's even doable?

Comment: Newton's method for non-linear systems would be a good choice

Comment: Notice that combining the second and third equations, you have $r$ as a function of $y,z$. From the second, you have $s$ as a function of $y$ using Lambert function. So $w$ can be expressed as a function of $y,z$.

Comment: @feddy: blindly jumping to a general solver is not the best idea. It will be numerically inefficient, and, worse, gives you no insight on the solution. A little observations shows that only the second equation is transcendental, and has a well-studied form, solved by the Lambert function. Even if this function is missing in your toolset, its known properties give you indications on the number of solutions or the asymptotic behavior...

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're totally right. I misunderstood the question, I taught that the OP just wanted a numerical solution :)

Answer (score 1):

With $$s=1/2\,{\rm W} \left(2\,y\right)$$ (where W is the so called-LambertW-function) and $$r=\frac{z-2y}{2y+1}$$ you can eliminate $r,s$

Answer (score 0):

An explicit form is not possible without the recourse to the Lambert function, as shown by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.

Anyway, you can write the delicious implicit form below:

$$(w+1)^2(z+1)^2\left(\log(w+1)+\log(z+1)-\log(2y+1)\right)^3-27y^3(2y+1)^2=0.$$